# Casual place-markers in an MS Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks, microsoft-word-2016

Is there any way to quickly and informally add an unofficial place marker (bookmark) to an MS Word (2016) document? I find I want this so I can quickly mark where I am, drift off somewhere reading something, and click-click and I'm back where I started. Creating bookmarks, with all it's "paperwork" would work, but I don't want my little hooks or flags messing with a document's potentially official and meaningful bookmarks.

Comment: I just insert *XXXXXX* and then search for that later.

Comment: @Chenmunka Yes, that can work, and if you use something rare like 6 Xs, you can insert more than one and just cycle through them.

Answer (score 3):

I insert a comment from the **Review** tab. If it's the only comment in the document, I can then click **Next** or (**Previous**) to go there instantly.

If the document already includes or will include other comments, I typically type something like **xxx** or **<<** as the comment text. I can then search on that text in the Navigation pane and go to the correct spot just as instantly.

Comment: I like this. If the document has other review comments, I can treat them as other bookmarks and just cycle through them. My only issue here is maybe interfering with real review comments.